# Not able to setup administrator password with cloudbase-init

Tags: windows-server-2019, cloud-init

i try to install a windows server 2019 with cloudbase-init. I did the following steps to do this:

- Install a Windows Server 2019 with Desktop Experience
- Install Cloudbase-Init
- Added the following lines to "Cloudbase-init.conf" and "Cloudbase-init-unattend.conf".

`metadata_services=cloudbaseinit.metadata.services.nocloudservice.NoCloudConfigDriveService plugins=cloudbaseinit.plugins.common.sethostname.SetHostNamePlugin,cloudbaseinit.plugins.windows.createuser.CreateUserPlugin,cloudbaseinit.plugins.common.setuserpassword.SetUserPasswordPlugin,cloudbaseinit.plugins.common.networkconfig.NetworkConfigPlugin,cloudbaseinit.plugins.common.sshpublickeys.SetUserSSHPublicKeysPlugin,cloudbaseinit.plugins.common.localscripts.LocalScriptsPlugin,cloudbaseinit.plugins.windows.licensing.WindowsLicensingPlugin`

- Then i did the sysprep, exported the VM and created a new Hyper-V VM based on teh previous export.
- The i created a cidata-iso file where i stored meta-data, user-data and network-config files.

meta-data

```
instance-id: win2019-test
local-hostname: win2019-test
admin-pass: Start123
```

network-config

```
version: 1
config:
  - type: physical
    name: interface0
    mac_address: 52:54:00:bd:f9:87
    subnets:
      - type: static
        address: 192.168.28.10
        netmask: 255.255.255.0
        gateway: 192.168.28.1
        dns_nameservers:
          - 192.168.28.1
```

user-data

```
#cloud-config
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
users:
  - name: gisela
    gecos: "Local user created by cloud-init"
    primary_group: Administrators
    passwd: Start123
    inactive: false
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh-rsa 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 root@hildegard
runcmd:
  - 'echo Custom settings "hello-world from user-data cloud-init script" > C:\Windows\Logs\hello-cloud-init.txt'
```

When i mount the ISO file and start the VM, it is impossible to login. Administrator is choosen as Login-User and the password is NOT Start123. I think it is randomly generated. Also it is not possible to chooose gisela as User to login. Therefore i am not able to access logfiles.

What i have to do to set the Administrator Password to "Start123"?

Regards

Dave